# How to query date range using between in Varchar(10) format mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: mysql, date, varchar, between

I am trying to only show records where "DateDue" is within the last year.  The trouble is my date is in the format of Varchar(10) as a result of my data feeds coming into my database on intervals from a vendor.  Obviously, the dates are not being filtered properly using this query.  Is it possible to convert this (temporarily for sake of comparing the date range) to the proper date data type for use in the query, but not permanently alter the type for that column?

```
SELECT `DocNum`, `DateDue` 
FROM `prod_po_list` 
WHERE `DateDue` BETWEEN (DATE_FORMAT(curdate( ) - INTERVAL 365 DAY , '%m/%d/%Y' ))
AND DATE_FORMAT( CURDATE( ) , '%m/%d/%Y' )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
 SELECT DocNum, DateDue 
 FROM prod_po_list
 WHERE STR_TO_DATE(DateDue, '%m/%d/%Y')
       BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 365 DAY)
       AND CURDATE()
```

Comment: Possibly, but I'm getting:
#1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'STR_TO_DATE'

Comment: @TimS  oops, one comma was missing (`STR_TO_DATE(DateDue, '%m/%d/%Y')`). Corrected it.

Comment: Thank you.  I am getting a different error now:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND CURDATE()

Comment: Oh I see...it's an extra opening parenthesis after Date_Sub( - working now

Comment: @TimS Thanks! I removed the extra brace from the answer. If you think, this was helpful, then don't forget to accept the answer to close thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you have index on date column this will be helpful

```
SELECT DocNum, DateDue 
 FROM prod_po_list
 WHERE DateDue >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 365 DAY)
       AND DateDue <= CURDATE()
```